# tinymce: how to remove body styles from style_formats menu

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I've defined some styles for tinymce in the styles_format menu. Works fine, except there are extra entries that seem to be imported from my CSS. They are classes that are only applied to the body so they can't be selected, but they are polluting the menu.

How can I get those body classes out of the menu?

(tinymce v4:6.5)
[image: body classes not wanted in styles_format menu]

Answer (score 0):

Great joy! There are options to filter the list.

```
importcss_selector_filter: '.my-prefix-',
style_formats: ...
```

So that only classes beginning with "my-prefix-" will automatically be included in the formats menu. It's part of the importcss plugin.